# ¿Como saber si un mismo valor se repite de forma consecutiva cierto numero de veces en una columna?

Tags: excel, tablas

Formo parte de un grupo de un juego en el que buscamos poder realizar torneos a distancia.

Para lograr ésto, tenemos que completar 30 días de interacción entre todos los participantes. Entonces armamos una tabla donde cada uno va completando los días que le falta con otro para lograr ese objetivo y cuando lo cumple, le pone un OK.

La duda es si existe algún programa, función de excel, etc que nos permita sacar automáticamente quienes pueden jugar el torneo por tener todos en simultáneo los 30 días de interacción cumplida.

Muchas gracias!

[image: Les dejo una porción de la tabla]

Comment: Tu ejemplo no termina de estar claro. ¿Qué representa el OK en cada columna? Supongo que significa que 2 jugadores han completado su partido. Para participar en el torneo, ¿tienen que tener todo oks? Es que lo que parece es que quieres algo que te de una lista de los que pueden jugar cada día o algo así, o los que todavía están pendientes por jugar un día en concreto

Comment: Si pudieses compartir el archivo cambiando los nombres para proteger la identidad se agradecería.
Puedes poner Nombre 1, Nombre 2 etc para sustituir los nombres si te quedas más tranquilo.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco he encontrado la siguiente formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:K1,"<>OK")=0
```

Esta formula devuelve el numero de celdas que no contienen la palabra "OK", entonces devuelve un `TRUE` si el numero de diferencias es 0 (todas las celdas son iguales).

Cabe destacar que "A1:K1" es el rango de las celdas utilziadas para el ejemplo y tu necesitas las tuyas propias.

Mas informacion en este [link](https://exceljet.net/formula/multiple-cells-have-same-value)

Comment: No es eso l que necesito me parece. Por ejemplo: viendo la imagen, se puede decir que el jugador 2 y 3 pueden participar sí o sí. Pero el jugador 1 puede participar si el 4 no juega o viceversa (tanto el 1 y el 4 tienen el OK con el 2 y el 3, pero el 1 y 4 no se tienen entre si). Yo quería encontrar una manera automática de que me diga por ejemplo si dejo afuera al 1, pueden participar todos estos jugadores (que me de la lista) o si saco el 4, pueden participar todos éstos jugadores.

Comment: Que termine decidiendo la máquina, de acuerdo todos esos escenerios, quienes pueden jugar porque dan la mayor cantidad de jugadores posibles.

Answer (score 0):

Para probar esto no es necesario pero por ser prácticos, puedes poner un ComboBox en la isma hoja al lado de la tabla y un Botón para hacerlo más fácil.

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta el código sería el siguiente:

```
 Public Function EnArray(Str As String, arr() As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = Str Then
            EnArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    EnArray = False
End Function

Sub Jugadores()
    Dim Jug() As String
    Dim RangoOk As Range, RangoT As Range
    Dim i, J, K As Integer

    K = 1
    ReDim Jug(1 To 1)
    Set RangoOk = Hoja1.Range("$E$8:$H$11")
    Set RangoT = Hoja1.Range("$E$7:$H$11")

    For i = 1 To RangoOk.Columns.Count
        For J = 1 To RangoOk.Rows.Count
            With RangoOk
                If .Cells(i, J) = "OK" _
                And .Cells(J, i) = "OK" Then
                    'VER SI EL JUGADOR YA ESTÁ EN LA MATRIZ O LISTA DE JUGADORES.
                    Dim Valor As String
                    Valor = RangoT(1, i).Value2
                    If EnArray(Valor, Jug) = False Then
                        ReDim Preserve Jug(1 To K)
                        Jug(K) = Valor
                        K = K + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next J
    Next i

    With Hoja1
        .ComboBox1.Clear
        For i = 1 To Application.CountA(Jug)
            .ComboBox1.AddItem Jug(i)
        Next i

        With .ComboBox1
            If .ListCount > 0 Then
                .ListIndex = 0
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

La función *EnArray* es para saber si en una matriz has metido ya o no a un jugador (para que no haya nombres duplicados).

Luego la función Jugadores recorre las filas y las columnas de la siguiente manera:

Se comprueba si en la celda del rango con los indice I y J hay un OK y luego se invierten la J y la Y para comprobar si la celda del jugador opuesto también tiene un OK.

En caso de que haya OK en los 2 casos, mira si el nombre del jugador de la columna en la que estamos está ya en la lista y si no lo mete.

Cuando la lista de jugadores está rellena, agrega los nombres a un ComboBox o Lista desplegable y selecciona por defecto el primer valor de la lista (si esta contiene valores).

**PARA EL COMMANDBUTTON O BOTÓN:**
Dentro de la Hoja donde tienes los datos, el botón y la lista (que en mi caso es Hoja1) pones una función para el evento Click del botón.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   'Llamamos al Sub para actualizar la lista con los jugadores
   Jugadores
End Sub
```

Y si quieres que se ejecute el código al abrir el libro excel, dentro de Thisworkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Jugadores
End Sub
```

Esa sería la explicación.
AJUSTA LOS RANGOS A NECESIDAD EN EL CÓDIGO.

Así se ve en mi caso la hoja excel donde están los datos y el botón:
[image: PANTALLAZO DE DATOS DE JUGADORES]

Espero que fuera lo que querías.